# assert_select not working in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, haml, integration-testing

I've scoured the internet for an answer and found nothing... this is driving me insane!

No `assert_select` statements are working in any of my tests. I've repeatedly confirmed that the element is actually in the dom on the targeted page — and it is — but every test fails on an assert_select statement. Even one as general as `assert_select 'body'`!

**Here's one test:**

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersIndexTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    def setup
        @user = users(:matt)
    end

    test "index including pagination" do
        log_in_as(@user)
        get users_path
        assert_template 'users/index'
        assert_select 'div.pagination'
        User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
            assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: user.first_name
        end
    end
end
```

**Here's users/index.html.haml**

```
%h1 All Users

= link_to 'New User', new_user_path

= will_paginate

%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th
      %th First name
      %th Last name
      %th Email
      %th
      %th
      %th

  %tbody
    - @users.each do |user|
      %tr
        %td= gravatar_for(user)
        %td= user.first_name
        %td= user.last_name
        %td= user.email
        %td= link_to 'Show', user
        %td= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user)
        %td= link_to 'Destroy', user, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }

= will_paginate
```

Pretty boring stuff, right? And yet, **the test fails**:

```
FAIL["test_index_including_pagination", UsersIndexTest, 0.9574]
 test_index_including_pagination#UsersIndexTest (0.96s)
        Expected at least 1 element matching "div.pagination", found 0..
        Expected 0 to be >= 1.
        test/integration/users_index_test.rb:12:in `block in <class:UsersIndexTest>'
```

Even when I change the assertion to `assert_select div`, it fails. And, again, I can confirm that the div is present when I visit the index page.

What am I missing here!?!?!?!

If it helps, here's my gemfile:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails',                  '4.2.0'
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'puma'
    gem 'turbolinks'
    gem 'jquery-rails'
    gem 'bcrypt',                 '~> 3.1.7'
    gem 'faker',                  '~> 1.4.2'
    gem 'sass-rails',             '~> 5.0.1'
    gem 'bootstrap-sass',         '~> 3.2.0'
    gem 'will_paginate',          '~>3.0.7'
    gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate','~>0.0.10'
    gem 'uglifier',               '>= 2.5.0'
    gem 'haml-rails',             '~> 0.8'
    gem 'jbuilder',               '~> 2.2.3'
    gem 'sdoc',                   '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
    gem 'rest-client',            '~> 1.7.3'
    gem 'bourbon'

    group :development, :test do
      gem 'byebug'
      gem 'web-console',          '~> 2.0.0'
      gem 'spring'
      gem 'better_errors'
    end

    group :test do
      gem 'minitest-reporters',   '~> 1.0.5'
      gem 'mini_backtrace',       '~> 0.1.3'
      gem 'guard-minitest',       '~> 2.3.1'
    end

    group :production do
      gem 'rails_12factor'
    end

    ruby '2.2.0'
```

Thanks to Steve Klein for the suggestion of printing out the response body. Unfortunately, the plot only thickens. The body clearly has the tag I'm targeting!

**Added a line to the above test**

```
assert_template 'users/index'
puts @response.body
assert_select 'div.pagination'
```

And the output has the tag!

← Previous 1

2

Next →

And yet still fails!!!

```
FAIL["test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links", UsersIndexTest, 1.412393] test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links#UsersIndexTest (1.41s)
    Expected at least 1 element matching "div.pagination", found 0..
    Expected 0 to be >= 1.
    test/integration/users_index_test.rb:15:in `block in <class:UsersIndexTest>'
```

Comment: can you include the output of "puts @response.body"?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are loading enough test data to trigger pagination.  This selector won't be on your page unless pagination kicks in (depends on how you have configured will_paginate in your controller action).

Comment: The assert_select doesn't even find a div on the page, so the pagination itself isn't the problem. It seems like it does not have access to the html at all.

Comment: Have you tried adding `puts @response.body` to your test to see what is rendered?

Comment: Good call @Steve, should have done that earlier. Funny enough, it prints out correctly and even has a `<div class="pagination">` tag!

Comment: Logically, this doesn't make much sense, so not sure what else to suggest.  I'm not sure how your routes are configured, but maybe adding `assert_redirect_to users_path` (or whatever) and then `follow_redirect!` before asserting template or selects.  Just to be extra sure you are where you think you are.  Ultimately, the silver lining might be that this drives you to rspec/Capybara, etc. which I find a lot easier to use.

Comment: It really does not any sense at all. That being the case, I do appreciate the attempt at troubleshooting. Thanks for the help; rspec, here I come!

Comment: I am stuck at this exact spot and I have no idea why either. When looking at the source code I can see that the pagination is there but the test still fails.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the problem lies in line 13: `User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|`. Try commenting the loop or cutting it out and run the test again. If it succeeds now, it could be that you have changed the default pagination method in your /users_controller.rb file. Try matching your custom pagination method with the one in your integration test. Something like the following for example: `User.paginate(page: 1, per_page: 10).each do |user|`

Comment: This indeed solved the problem I had. The number of records per page in both the test and the controller should be the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with `assert_select 'div.pagination'`, so I cought this thread googling the error.

I read the thread and got back to my app.
I tried to test:

```
assert_select 'div'
```

which passed.
I then switched back to:

```
assert_select 'div.pagination'
```

and test passed as well :O

For your reference, this is my users_index_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
class UsersIndexTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

def setup
  @user = users(:archer)
end  

test "index including pagination" do
  log_in_as(@user)
  get users_path
  assert_template 'users/index'
  assert_select 'div.pagination'
  User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
    assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: user.name
  end
end
end
```

and this is my fixture users.yml

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>

archer:
  name: Sterling Archer
  email: duchess@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>

lana:
  name: Lana Kane
  email: hands@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>

mallory:
  name: Mallory Archer
  email: boss@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>

<% 30.times do |n| %>
  user_<%= n %>:
  name:  <%= "User #{n}" %>
  email: <%= "user-#{n}@example.com" %>
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
<% end %>
```

I really don't know why now it pass, but I wanted to contribute in the research of a more logical solution.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your fixture file for typos and make sure that you are indeed loading enough comments to trigger inclusion of a pagination.

I had the same problem as you, originating from chapter 13 of the Ruby on Rails Tutorial. I included 'puts response.body' in my test and discovered that the ERb comments that I attempted to generate in my "comments.yml" were not being generated during the test. The issue turned out to be that I forgot a single '=' sign in an ERb tag. Hopefully for you the solution is equally simple!

Answer (score 0):

For whoever runs into this problem in the future, knowing fully well you tried all of the solutions above and nothing changed.
Pay attention to this line in the users.yml file

Wrong:

```
<% 30.times do |n| %>
user_<%= n %>:
name: <%= "User #{n}" %>
email: <%= "user-#{n}@example.com" %>
password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
<% end %>
```

Wrong:

```
<% 30.times do |n| %>
  user_<%= n %>:
  name: <%= "User #{n}" %>
  email: <%= "user-#{n}@example.com" %>
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
<% end %>
```

Correct:

```
<% 30.times do |n| %>
user_<%= n %>:
  name: <%= "User #{n}" %>
  email: <%= "user-#{n}@example.com" %>
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
<% end %>
```